# Display long table in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

Is there a way to display a table with many columns nicely in `rmarkdown` PDF output? looking for some wrapper option to display it as say 3 consecutive tables but without breaking the data frame into 3 separate frames. Here is my chunk that makes the table very small and barely legible.

```
library(knitr)
library(readr)
library(kableExtra)
dat_url <- 'https://gender-pay-gap.service.gov.uk/viewing/download-data/2019'
dat <- read_csv(dat_url) 
kable(head(dat), caption='Sample Data: 6 rows', booktabs=TRUE, linesep="")  %>%
kable_styling(latex_options =c('striped', 'scale_down'))
```

Comment: @Werner - i'm saving it via YAML header as in `output: pdf_document`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'longtable = true' in kable to split table across pages, "repeat_header" to, you guessed it..

```
x_df %>% 
   kbl(caption = "caption", 
    align = "l",
    format = "latex",
    centering = FALSE,
    booktabs = TRUE,
    longtable = TRUE,
    linesep = "") %>% 
   kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), position = "left", full_width = F, fixed_thead = T, latex_options = c("striped", "HOLD_position", "repeat_header"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it worth, I broke the `dat` into 3 parts and `kable`d all separately:

```
 kable(head(dat[,1:7]), caption='Original Data: first 6 rows', booktabs=TRUE, linesep="")  %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options =c('striped', 'scale_down', 'hold_position'))

  kable(head(dat[,8:18]), booktabs=TRUE, linesep="")  %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options =c('striped', 'scale_down', 'hold_position'))
  
  kable(head(dat[,19:22]), booktabs=TRUE, linesep="")  %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options =c('striped', 'scale_down', 'hold_position'))
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to use `kable`. I prefer to use `xtable` and using LaTeX code.

```
library(xtable)
print(xtable::xtable(dat[1:30,c(1,3)], align="ll|c"), 
      hline.after = F,
      include.rownames=F, 
      include.colnames = F,
      tabular.environment = 'longtable',
      caption.width = "8.5in",
      comment=F,
      floating = F,
      add.to.row = list(pos = list(0),
                        command =
                          paste("\\caption{ZzZzZzZz} \n \\label{tab:tb1} \n \\\\ \\hline \\hline \n",
                                " \\textbf{Employer Name} & \\textbf{Sic Codes}\\\\ \\hline \n",  
                      "\\endhead \n", 
                                " \\multicolumn{2}{r}{\\footnotesize \\emph{Continued on next page...}} \n \\\\                    
                                 \\endfoot \\hline \\hline
                                 \\endlastfoot \n",collapse=" ")))
```

> The code is a bit long but it should work

[image]